# 'Since' implies George Washington is an independent run or not?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> While **no independent** has won the presidency **since** George Washington,
>   Democrats fear that Schultz would almost certainly split their vote
>   and give Trump an easier path to re-election.

'Since George Washington' means from George Washington or from the next after George Washington?

Let assumption that there was a female president A. Then after A, all the presidents are males. A's successor is B. So we can say,

> There was no female president since A.

or

> There was no female president since B.

Comment: It is best not to accept answers so quickly, as other may come along with more information. And point out the answer is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is an elliptical remark and that it *does* imply that Washington was an independent.

> While no independent has won the presidency since George Washington [won the presidency as one], Democrats fear ...

Compare:

> No one has seen a Yeti since Zhang's 1947 expedition to the Himalayas.

That sentence is understood to mean that the last sighting occurred in 1947.

P.S. Natural language isn't symbolic logic. It allows us to be clear and unambiguous but does not force us to be.

Comment: I will add the example "best thing since sliced bread" says sliced bread was a great idea, and this is the best new idea since then.

Comment: I think you are right about George Washington's affiliation, but the situation is complicated slightly by the fact that he was the first president. So it's possible his name would be mentioned as a more concrete and interesting way to say "since the beginning", or "ever". If "the temperature never hit 110 degrees F, since temperatures began to be recorded in 1887", that doesn't mean it got up to 110 in 1887.

Comment: @Lorel C: There's the possibility of ambiguity.  How would you understand the following sentence? *The temperature has never hit 110F, not since temperatures first began to be recorded in 1887.*

Comment: Well, I would think,"ha, that sounds like it was super-hot in 1887, but that's silly, the writer just means, '*never*'." But yes, exactly, it's ambiguous, and your adding that 'not' makes it closer to the 50/50 line.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really imply anything with respect to whether George Washington was an independent or not. All it says is that since the times of George Washington, there has been no independent political candidate who has become the president of the United States of America:

> While no [**independent political candidate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_politician) has won the presidency **since the times of George Washington**, Democrats fear that Schultz would almost certainly split their vote and give Trump an easier path to re-election.

If you want to know whether George Washington ran as an independent candidate, you have to specifically look that information up.

Comment: Let assumption that there was a female president A. Then after A, all the presidents are male. A's successor is B. So we can say, "There is no female president since A or since B"?

Comment: Please, if you have something new to ask, then post a new question. Don't try to alter the original question to the point where it begins to deviate from what you were asking originally.

Comment: I think it still would mean the same thing as I explained in my answer.

Comment: It normal usage it does say that he was an independent.

Comment: +1 We might *assume* it means that George Washington was an independent, but it by no means *necessitates* he was. It's clunky language if it doesn't, but people use clunky language all the time.

Comment: @Zhang *No alien has abducted me since yesterday.* That statement is true. It's also true that no alien *did* abduct me yesterday—nor did I claim that one did. If you thought I meant that, then it was simply an incorrect assumption.